# Insert checkbox in each column of a datagriview in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to code-build a checkbox in my calendar datagridview.

With the following stored procedure I am building the calendar SQL SERVER

```
  SET LANGUAGE Español
        set @PERIODO  = @PERIODO

        declare @columnas varchar(max)= ''

        select @columnas =  coalesce(@columnas + '[' + cast(DIAS as varchar(12)) + '],', '')
        FROM (Select c.NombreDiaCorto+CONVERT(varchar(2),c.DIA) AS DIAS
            From AUT_CALENDARIO c
            --where @FechaInicio<=c.FECHA and c.FECHA<=@FechaFin
            where @PERIODO=substring(c.IDCALENDARIO,1,6)
            ) as DTM

        set @columnas = left(@columnas,LEN(@columnas)-1)
        --Select @columnas 
        DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(MAX);

        set @SQLString = N'
        SELECT TOP 1 * 
        into TEMP_CALENDARIO
        FROM
        (Select 0 as X, c.NombreDiaCorto+CONVERT(varchar(2),c.DIA) AS DIAS
            from AUT_CALENDARIO c
            CROSS APPLY AUT_PERSONAL p
            where substring(c.IDCALENDARIO,1,6)='''+ @PERIODO+'''
            ) AS TABLA
        PIVOT
        (
        MAX(X)
        FOR DIAS IN (' + @columnas + ')
        ) AS PivotTable;'

        --SELECT  @SQLString
        EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLString

        --UPDATE T SET T.IDCODIGOGENERAL='' FROM TEMP_CALENDARIO T
        Select * FROM TEMP_CALENDARIO

        IF OBJECT_ID('TEMP_CALENDARIO') IS NOT NULL  BEGIN drop table TEMP_CALENDARIO END
```

And I am displaying it in my datagridview with the following code snippet.

```
   Sub listar_periodos()
    Try
        Me.dgvdias.DataSource = negHor.Listar_Calendarios(VGlobales.Base, Me.cboperiodo.SelectedValue)
    Catch ex1 As SqlClient.SqlException : MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message, "MENSAJES", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Catch ex As Exception : MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MENSAJES", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And it is displayed as follows, so far so good

[image]

---

But what I need is to replace the "0" with a checkbox control and thus allow me to select the day that I want, and quite apart to obtain the name of the column or the position that I have selected but so far I have not found the function or the logic of how to insert a checkbox any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: If you're selecting a single specific day, seems like a radio button (or even listbox) might be more appropriate. In fact, the more I think about the more I think ListBox instead of DataGrid is the way to go here.

Comment: The "0" that show I want to replace it with a checkbox to be able to select the days, I understand that you must first go through and count how many columns there are and from there add the checkboxes

Comment: How are you creating the DataGridView and columns?  Did you do this via the designer with auto populate columns turned on?

Comment: the columns and the row have been created by means of a Stored Procedure from SQL place the SP in the case, I only call it with a datagridview.datasource = here I call the function that calls the stored procedure.

Comment: You’re likely to find that setting the dgv up at design time with the required columns that have the required controls, the turn off the auto populate column properly

Comment: Of course when the table is created manually or by design, the checkbox field can be added

But this calendar is dynamic, there are months that have 30 days or 31 or 28 like February, that is why it would not apply to create by design

Comment: At runtime then you will need to configure the columns yourself looking at the DataGridViewColumnCollection to set the appropriate controls https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Agree with @Hursey in the the above recommendations.  Another angle would be to first population a non-SQL DataGridView with the data and checkboxes you want, and then merge that code with automated data from SQL.   What you want is independent from SQL.